# Правильный подсчет значений

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Есть код, который формирует словарь из данных json

Пример данных из json:
[ссылка](https://gitlab.com/Vladislav.Skibenko/json.git)

Сам код

```
 import os
        import re
        import json
        import collections
        
     

   # Initialization collection for all lvl
    rule0 = collections.defaultdict(int) #
    rule1 = collections.defaultdict(int) #
    rule2 = collections.defaultdict(int) #
    rule3 = collections.defaultdict(int) #
    rule4 = collections.defaultdict(int) #
    rule5 = collections.defaultdict(int) #
    
    MY_RULE = {}
    
    # run comandline for create json
    # MY_PAT = os.system(r'pmd -d C:\Users\vsi\int\sfdevops_metrics\.project\na_gold\force-app\main\default\classes -R C:\Users\vsi\int\sfdevops_metrics\.project\na_gold\__PMD\GOLD_ruleset.xml -f json > C:\Users\vsi\int\sfdevops_metrics\.project\SM-774\output.json')
    
    #open json
    with open(r'C:\Users\vsi\int\sfdevops_metrics\.project\SM-774\output.json') as json_file:
        MY_PATH = json.load(json_file, object_hook=None)
    
    #refactor json
    for values in MY_PATH['files']:
        for i in values['violations']:
            if i['priority'] == 1:
                rule1[i['priority']] += 1
            elif i.get('priority') == 2:
                rule2[i['priority']] += 1
            elif i.get('priority') == 3:
                rule3[i['priority']] += 1
            elif i.get('priority') == 4:
                rule4[i['priority']] += 1
            elif i.get('priority') == 5:
                rule5[i['priority']] += 1
            rule0[i['priority']] += 1
        for key1 in values.items():
            key1 = str(key1)
            key1 = re.findall(r'C:.*', key1)
            key1 = str(key1)
            key1 = key1.replace(r'"C:\\\\Users\\\\vsi\\\\int\\\\sfdevops_metrics\\\\.project\\\\na_gold\\\\force-app\\\\main\\\\default\\\\classes\\\\', '')
            key1 = key1.replace("')\"", '')
            rule6 = str(rule0).replace("defaultdict(<class 'int'>, ", '')
            rule7 = str(rule1).replace("defaultdict(<class 'int'>, ", '')
            rule8 = str(rule2).replace("defaultdict(<class 'int'>, ", '')
            rule9 = str(rule3).replace("defaultdict(<class 'int'>, ", '')
            rule10 = str(rule4).replace("defaultdict(<class 'int'>, ", '')
            rule11 = str(rule5).replace("defaultdict(<class 'int'>, ", '')
        # MY_RULE[a] = values
    
            MY_RULE[key1] = MY_RULE.get(key1, []) + [( rule7, rule8, rule9, rule10, rule11)]
    del MY_RULE['[]']
    
            # print(a)
    # for i in values['violations']:
    #     print(i[''])
    
        # print(rule0)
    print(MY_RULE)
```

Я собирался посчитать кол-во приоритетов для каждого файла, но в итоге он считает все приоритеты для всех файлов и соотвественно суммирует их между собой по номеру критерию и в конце получается {4: 3965, 2: 6572, 3: 1285, 1: 129, 5: 65}
Как мне изменить код, чтобы приоритеты считались только в рамке одного файла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для корректного отчета коллекции достаточно было обнулять ее после записи

```
import os
import re
import json
import collections

# Initialization collection for all lvl
rule0 = collections.defaultdict(int) #
rule1 = collections.defaultdict(int) #
rule2 = collections.defaultdict(int) #
rule3 = collections.defaultdict(int) #
rule4 = collections.defaultdict(int) #
rule5 = collections.defaultdict(int) #

MY_RULE = {}

# run comandline for create json
# MY_PAT = os.system(r'pmd -d C:\Users\vsi\int\sfdevops_metrics\.project\na_gold\force-app\main\default\classes -R C:\Users\vsi\int\sfdevops_metrics\.project\na_gold\__PMD\GOLD_ruleset.xml -f json > C:\Users\vsi\int\sfdevops_metrics\.project\SM-774\output.json')

#open json
with open(r'C:\Users\vsi\int\sfdevops_metrics\.project\SM-774\output.json') as json_file:
    MY_PATH = json.load(json_file, object_hook=None)

#refactor json
for values in MY_PATH['files']:
    for key1 in values.items():
        # print(key1)
        key1 = str(key1)
        priority = re.findall(r'priority....', key1)
        # priority = str(priority)
        for i in values['violations']:
            if i['priority'] == 1:
                rule1[i['priority']] += 1
            elif i.get('priority') == 2:
                rule2[i['priority']] += 1
            elif i.get('priority') == 3:
                rule3[i['priority']] += 1
            elif i.get('priority') == 4:
                rule4[i['priority']] += 1
            elif i.get('priority') == 5:
                rule5[i['priority']] += 1
            rule0[i['priority']] += 1
        # # rule0[i['priority']] += 1
        # print(key1)
        key1 = re.findall(r'C:.*', key1)
        key1 = str(key1)
        key1 = key1.replace(r'"C:\\\\Users\\\\vsi\\\\int\\\\sfdevops_metrics\\\\.project\\\\na_gold\\\\force-app\\\\main\\\\default\\\\classes\\\\', '')
        key1 = key1.replace("')\"", '')
        # print(key1)
        rule6 = str(rule0).replace("defaultdict(<class 'int'>, ", '')
        # rule7 = str(rule1).replace("defaultdict(<class 'int'>, ", '')
        # rule8 = str(rule2).replace("defaultdict(<class 'int'>, ", '')
        # rule9 = str(rule3).replace("defaultdict(<class 'int'>, ", '')
        # rule10 = str(rule4).replace("defaultdict(<class 'int'>, ", '')
        # rule11 = str(rule5).replace("defaultdict(<class 'int'>, ", '')

        MY_RULE[key1] = MY_RULE.get(key1, []) + [(rule6)]
        rule0 = collections.defaultdict(int)  #
        # rule1 = collections.defaultdict(int)  #
        # rule2 = collections.defaultdict(int)  #
        # rule3 = collections.defaultdict(int)  #
        # rule4 = collections.defaultdict(int)  #
        # rule5 = collections.defaultdict(int)  #
del MY_RULE['[]']
MY_RULE['FULL ATTENTIONS ON BRANCH'] = rule6

# print(a)
# for i in values['violations']:
#     print(i[''])

    # print(rule0)
print(MY_RULE)
# print(rule1)
```